# don't start application that targets .net framework under 4.5 in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have windows 7 ultimate sp1 and visual studio 2013 with latest updates
and I have avira internet security

I target .net framework 3.5 for my applications.

Most of the times when I click on start button to run application in debug mode show me this error:

[image]

even I have this problem on windows 8.1

I disabled avira firewall but dont solved my problem.

I searched in google but not found any right solution for my problem :(

Comment: The error message is telling you it is trying to run the application remotely, is that what you want to do?

Comment: no !!! the application is in my computer and is not in other computer

Comment: Something on the machine is interfering with the ability of Visual Studio to talk to the remote debugger.  Sure, anti-malware is on the top of that list.  You left no breadcrumbs.  You could limp along by forcing the EXE project to run in 32-bit mode so you don't need the remote debugger.

Comment: @HansPassant now how force the EXE project to run in 32-bit mode ??

Comment: Copy paste that question in a google query (without my name), take the first hit.  Try to not be helpless.

Comment: oh my problem solved with this guidance. thanks :)